# Whole txt file not read by doubly linked list

Tags: c++

I have been having an issue on reading a txt file by doubly link list whereby only the last line gets read and not the whole file. Below is my txt file and cpp file.

This is my .txt file:

```
ID    marks
S11111111 20
S22222222 65
S33333333 99
S44444444 15
S55555555 70
S66666666 10
S77777777 75
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class student {
  private: string id;
  int mark;
  public: void setid(string nid) {
    id=nid;
  }
  string getid() {
    return id;
  }
  void setmark(int nmark) {
    mark=nmark;
  }
  int getmark() {
    return mark;
  }
}

;
class node {
  private: student data;
  node *next;
  node *prev;
  node *head;
  node *tail;
  public: node() {
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
  }
  ~node() {
    cout<<"sample not clear decontructor"<<endl;
  }
  void readfile();
  void appendnode(node *pnode);
  void print();
}

;
void node::appendnode(node *pnode) {
  if (head==NULL) {
    head=pnode;
    pnode->prev=NULL;
  }
  else {
    tail->next=pnode;
    pnode->prev=tail;
  }
  tail=pnode;
  pnode->next=NULL;
}

void discard_line(ifstream &in);
void node::readfile() {
  node *pnode;
  ifstream file;
  string id=" ";
  int mark=0;
  file.open("students.txt");
  discard_line(file);
  while(file>>id>>mark) {
    pnode=new node;
    pnode->data.setid(id);
    pnode->data.setmark(mark);
    appendnode(pnode);
  }
}

void node::print() {
  node *pnode;
  for (pnode==head;
  pnode !=NULL;
  pnode=pnode->next) cout << pnode->data.getid()<<" "<<pnode->data.getmark() <<endl;
}

int main() {
  node cs;
  cs.readfile();
  cs.print();
}

void discard_line(ifstream &in) {
  char c;
  do in.get(c);
  while (c!='\n');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please tell us what "issue" you're having. What is the code supposed to do, what is it doing?

Comment: And no images of texts, copy-paste the actual text into the question instead (like you had it originally).

Comment: Does your print method actually have `for pnode==head...` instead of `for pnode=head...`?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: ID   marks                                                                                                        S11111111 20
S22222222 65
S33333333 99
S44444444 15
S55555555 70
S66666666 10
S77777777 75

Comment: Our time is not a substitute for your debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `void node::print()` you declare a `node*` called `pnode` - it is undefined.
Then, you go on and use a for loop like this:

```cpp
for(pnode == head; pnode != NULL; pnode = pnode->next){
    cout << pnode->data.getid() << " " << pnode->data.getmark() << endl;
}
```

The first part of the for loop does nothing, it only checks if your undefined variable is equal to head.
(`pnode == head`).

The third part of the for loop happens to do something illegal, since `pnode` is undefined, accessing its member `next` is **undefined behaviour**.
(`pnode = pnode->next`).

Replacing the for loop with this fixes the issue:

```cpp
for (pnode = head; pnode != NULL; pnode = pnode->next){
    ..
}
```

The difference between `==` and `=` is that the first one compares and the second one assigns.

Comment: Thank you so much, it actually worked.Appreciated

Comment: Please remember to up vote helpful answers and accept the correct ones. This helps everyone in the community ^^